# How to find a module in a virtualenv without activating said virtualenv?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
mkdir test && cd test
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install django
mkdir mod1
touch mod1/__init__.py
echo "a = 1" > mod1/mod2.py
```

Which gives me:

```
test/.venv
test/mod1/__init__.py
test/mod1/mod2.py
```

How would I write this function:

```
def get_module(module_name, root_path, virtualenv_path=None)
```

In order for this to work:

```
project_root_path = "./test"
project_virtualenv_path = "./test/.venv"

get_module("mod1.mod2", project_root_path, project_virtualenv_path)
get_module("django.contrib.auth", project_root_path, project_virtualenv_path)
```

Assuming I don't have `./test/.venv` activated.

The reason I want to do this, is because I'm working on a vim plugin which would implement `gf` functionality in a python file on an import statement. I'm trying to support virtualenvs as well.

EDIT:

Also, the script should not alter the current runtime, by adding or appending to sys.path. This should run inside vim, via the vim python bindings, and I don't think altering the vim python runtime would be a good idea.

`get_module` could either return a module object, or the path to the module, which is what I'm basically looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only practical solution I could find here is to run the virtualenv's `activate_this.py` script, look for what I need, then remove it's changes from `sys.path`.

```
import sys
import os

old_sys_path = list(sys.path)

virtualenv_path = "/path/to/venv"
activate_this_path = os.path.join(virtualenv_path, "bin", "activate_this.py")

execfile(activate_this_path, dict(__file__=activate_this_path))

# get my module here

# restore sys.path
sys.path = old_sys_path
```

If you have a better answer, please add it, and I'll change the accepted answer gladly.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your virtualenv on python path like:

```
import site 
site.addsitedir('/home/user/.virtualenvs/myapp1/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

and then import should work

Comment: there are two problems with that: **1)** it alters the runtime, which is bad (sry, edited the question with explanations) **2)** it only includes site-packages, suppose I want a package which was installed in `.test/.venv/src/`, which is often the case. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: it seems that when pip installs a package into `./test/.venv/src/`, it creates an `egg-link` in `site-packages`, and the `site` module knows how to add that. So **2)** is not an issue.